# Are cpp classes dynamically loaded?

Tags: c++, classloader

I know that the JVM has a separate class loader which is the default runtime method for loading classes and executing them. I just want to know how class loading works for cpp. And is class loading in cpp somewhat related to the dynamic loading in operating systems. If the classes are not dynamically loaded I guess there is no real need for heap allocation. But cpp obviously has the free() memory option. I'm slightly confused. How does it work exactly?

EDIT: I understood why the heap is required for object initialization. But the reasons for static or dynamic loading of classes itself is not clear to me, especially the way cpp does it.

Comment: You need heap allocation much more for object instantiation than for class loading.

Comment: Dynamic class loading and heap allocation (aka dynamic memory) are completely unrelated concepts. In fact it is rather unclear what you mean by "static or dynamic loading of classes". C++ language has no such concepts.

Comment: I think you're conflating [Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) and [dynamic memory allocation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) .. If you want the C++ equivalent of reflection, the closest you can find is [`RTTI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.
Once the code is compiled into an executable there are no classes, objects, methods and such: only bytes and machine instructions.

Dynamic memory has nothing to do with dynamic class loading. "Dynamic" memory implies that the size of the memory is not necessarily known at compile time and might only be known at runtime, with the ability to change and be resized, hence the "dynamic". Again, this is achieved using machine instructions which have no knowledge of classes.

The only thing that remotely resembles "class loading" is DLL loading. A DLL is compiled code which exports functions for other programs to use.
The DLL can be loaded and unloaded at runtime. And again, these exported functions are already machine instructions.

Comment: But atleast in the case of Java, classes have relevance at runtime too, right?. I just want to know how it is with cpp.

Comment: C++ is not Java. on runtime there is only machine instructions

Comment: In C++, classes are just a wrapper around code and data within a type system.  The specifics of how C++ classes are actually implemented by a compiler is a much bigger topic, and there are books about it.

Comment: `on runtime there is only machine instructions` .. this is true of ANY language :)

Comment: @txtechhelp not necesserly. every language is compiled to assembly in some stage, but most of the managed languages also keep the byte code available on runtime for reflection and such, so there is not only machine instructions, but machine instructions, bytecode, VM and JIT